# How to make example.com/about show example.com/about.html? (Apache2)

Tags: mod-rewrite, https, url, apache2

What is the best option to go when trying to have example.com/about show example.com/about.html, and without changing the url to /about.html. Right now i'm trying to the following code it just returns an 404 Error.

```
RewriteRule ^/about$ https://example.com/about.html [R=301,L]
```

Edit #1
To [w3dk](https://serverfault.com/users/49157/w3dk) i currently do have multiviews enable but i still get a 404 error. Here is my current current setup in VirtualHost

```
<Directory /var/www/public_html>
    Options All +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: Where are you using this directive? Directly in server config / VirtualHost, `<Directory>` section or `.htaccess`?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using mod_rewrite to *internally rewrite* the request, you could just use MultiViews (mod_negotiation) instead:

```
Options +MultiViews
```

mod_rewrite allows you to do more complex URL rewritting, however, if all you are doing is removing the file extension then MultiViews will suffice - it is what it's designed for.

When you make a request for `/about` (a URL/file without an extension in a valid directory) then with MultiViews enabled, mod_negotiation will search for a file that matches the expected mime-type and return that as an internal request.

**UPDATE:**

> ```
> Options All +MultiViews
> ```

This is not valid syntax (I assume you must be on Apache 2.2, as this would fail with an error during startup on Apache 2.4). As noted in the [Apache docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options):

> **Warning**
>   Mixing `Options` with a `+` or `-` with those without is not valid syntax and is likely to cause unexpected results.

To express `All` and `MultiViews` you would need two directives:

```
Options All
Options +MultiViews
```

`All` is the default (on Apache 2.2) so this might not be necessary. However, it would be preferable to specify just the options you require in a single directive, for example:

```
Options FollowSymLinks Includes MultiViews
```

Comment: with MultiViews it will work without displaying the extension .html even it is good for search engines but you can't use any file like about.php or about.htm in the same directory or a directory that has the same name so dir /help and file help.php can't be in the same place.

Answer (score 0):

can you please try it like this: I think it will work

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^about$ https://example.com/about.html [R=301,L]
```

You can also use redirect:

```
Redirect 301 /about http://example.com/about.html
Redirect 301 /any_dir/about http://example.com/about.html
```

Comment: "and without changing the url" - Your _redirect_ above would change the URL. However, it's not clear from the question where in the server config this directive is being used. So, depending on the context, it won't necessarily "work" (removing the slash prefix on the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ assumes a directory/.htaccess context).

Comment: @w3dk I have tested it and it will work in any directory that you would put the rule in 1st test http://bahv.net/about - 2nd test http://tools.bahv.net/about - 3rd test http://tools.bahv.net/help/about